# XPath to Parse "SRC" from IMG tag?

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, screen-scraping

Right now I successfully grabbed the full  element from an HTML page with this:

```
//img[@class='photo-large']
```

for example it would return this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" class='photo-large' />
```

But I only need the SRC url (http://example.com/img.jpg). Any help?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You are so close to answering this yourself that I am somewhat reluctant to answer it for you. However, the following XPath should provide what you want (provided the source is XHTML, of course).

```
//img[@class='photo-large']/@src
```

For further tips, check out [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com). They have excellent tutorials on such things and a great reference too.

Answer (score 9):

Using **Hpricot** this works:

```
doc.at('//img[@class="photo-large"]')['src']
```

In case you have more than one image, the following gives an array:

```
doc.search('//img[@class="photo-large"]').map do |e| e['src'] end
```

However, **Nokogiri** is [many times faster](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-xml-performance-benchmarks-1641.html) and it [*“can be used as a drop in replacement”*](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2008/10/30/nokogiri-is-released/) for Hpricot.
Here the version for Nokogiri, in which this XPath for selecting attributes works:

```
doc.at('//img[@class="photo-large"]/@src').to_s
```

or for many images:

```
doc.search('//img[@class="photo-large"]/@src').to_a
```

Comment: Stumbling upon this question, I can't help but wonder: what makes you answer referencing ruby related depencies? Seems pretty out of the blue to me.

Comment: @FabianPas I ask myself the same :D

Answer (score 0):

//img/@src

you can just go with this if you want a link of the image.

example:

```
<img alt="" class="avatar width-full rounded-2" height="230" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/...;s=460" width="230">
```