# Retrieve url from background-image

Tags: python, xpath

i've used following xPath to retrieve the background-image

```
//div[@class='opponent opponent2']/div[@class='team-player']/@style
```

This is the output below

```
background-image: url(\"/uploads/images/teams/test.jpeg\")
```

How can I retrieve the url only instead of the whole `background-image: url`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179641/xpath-to-parse-src-from-img-tag.

Comment: do you want to do this using only xPath? if not you can split this output so you get only the relative path you need.

Comment: how can i do that kostas?

Comment: user it is not the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
xpath_output = 'background-image: url(\"/uploads/images/teams/test.jpeg\")'

path = xpath_output.split('"')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
//div[@class='opponent opponent2']/div[@class='team-player']/@style
```

selects the correct value,

```
substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class='opponent opponent2']/div[@class='team-player']/@style,'\"'),'\"')
```

will select only

```
/uploads/images/teams/test.jpeg
```

This is rather unwieldy, and perhaps it would be easier to just retrieve the string as a whole, and then use Python's string functionalities to process it further.